# Gradle bitbucket/git release plugin

Tags: git, gradle, release, bitbucket

I am looking for the solution to release my gradle android aar library to specific bitbucket repository. I would expect it to simply install my artifact (result of `gradle install`) to specified repository and eventually tag it, with SSH support. I have found number of `gradle` `git` release plugins but either they do not support bitbucket repositories or SSH auth. Any tested solutions?

Comment: Don't know any such solution. As far as I know `uploadArchives` supports `maven`, `ivy` and flat files but nothing about `git`. I suppose to writing custom task will be the easiest and fastest solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is this tool http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/bitbucket.html
I am fiddling with it myself to make it work in my Gradle project.